# What is stored in the webserver? (Separated Database)

Tags: database

Assuming a classified website where real estate agents post their houses advertisement for rent or sale

When I built the server, I separated the database and the webserver

> Database Server: Ubuntu and MariaDB only
>
> Webserver: Ubuntu, Nginx, PHP, Redis, Wordpress

I have been wondering all the time what is actually being stored in webserver.

Say, if I destroy the webserver and create a new set of webserver (of course complete with all the same Wordpress plugin + theme), what do I lose?

I think I will only lose the house images that are uploaded by the house agents?

Also, is there any guide to do set up load balancer? Couldn't find a good one so far.

Thanks heaps

Comment: What is Redis being used for? I'm not sure that an absolute answer can be given here without a full copy of the codebase, a generic answer might not apply to you depending on what the developers have done

Comment: Redis is for object caching

Comment: THEORETICALLY, the webserver has all the files and the database has all the, well, data. So you *could* delete the files and restore the files with a new copy or whatever and as long as it points to the DB correctly you'll be fine. But in my experience WordPress doesn't like that very much.

Comment: I agree, except the images in the wp-content/uploads/ --- that's the bit problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WP database contains **everything** that is related to content: posts, pages, theme settings, plugin settings, media of all kinds. So if you were to replace the WP database with a brand-new WP database, **all of your content** - and many of your settings - **will be gone**.

The WP 'code' (PHP, CSS, JS source files) is stored in the wp-xxxxx folders, plus the site root. Some CSS might be stored in the WP database, but the 'core' code is in the site root and the wp-xxxxx folders.

Can't speak to load balancing...perhaps someone else will chime in on that.

Comment: I did some research. You are right, except any media/uploaded pictures go to wp-content/uploads folder. This is the confusing bit on how to set up multi server serving one website